# How to kill an orphan android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, adb

I have tried everything but the emulator keeps showing when I type "adb devices" in cmd, even though there is no trace of the emulator in the AVD Manager. I have re-installed sdk tools, re-started my pc several times, but not matter what the emulator is still there. I have also deleted the auto generated folder .android. What should I do ?

Comment: have you used the command "adb kill-server" on command promt

Comment: yes I have done that as well .. but it did not worked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

adb usb

to make sure USB connection is used and "orphans" are cleared.